# Create ascii numeric String from string

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to create a numeric String of the ascii values from a given String.
My string only contains upercase A-Z chars.

At the moment I have:

```
String example = "STRING";
List<Integer> list = example.chars()
          .mapToObj(item -> (int) item)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output: `[83, 84, 82, 73, 78, 71]`

Than I do:

```
String asciiString = list.stream()
            .map( n -> n.toString() )
            .collect( Collectors.joining( "" ) );
```

Output: `838482737871`

Is there a more effective way to do it? Possibly with only one stream?

Comment: Don't collect into a list. Add the map and collect to your original stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `mapToObj` and convert it to string.

```
 String result = example.chars()
            .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
```